# Code is not running through entire text file

Tags: delphi, text-files, pascal

I have a program that is supposed to cycle through a text file to see whether a username is already taken.

For some reason, the code isn't going through the entire file. It is stopping after 3 lines. I have the usernames stored in 26 text files (1 for each letter). It accesses the text file by copying the first letter of the username and opening the corresponding file:

```pascal
AssignFile(tfile, Upcase(sUsername[1]) + '.txt');
//if username is Alex, it would open 'A.txt'
```

For example
(Username#Password#OtherInfo)

```
Alex#123#Beta
Andrew#987#Gamma
alexis#abcd#Alpha
Anderson#zxcvbnm#Gamma
```

My code would stop after the third name.

```pascal
AssignFile(tfile, Upcase(sUsername[1]) + '.txt');
Reset(tfile);
while not Eof(tfile) do
begin
  Readln(tfile, sline);
  iPos := Pos('#', sline);
  if sUsername = Copy(sline, 1, iPos - 1) then
  begin
    bFlag := True;
  end;
end;
if bFlag = True then
begin
  ShowMessage('That username is already taken');
  CloseFile(tfile);
end
else
begin
  Append(tfile);
  Write(tfile, #13);
  Write(tfile, sUsername + '#' + sPassword + '#' + rgpUserType.Items[rgpUserType.ItemIndex]); // adds new user to text file
  CloseFile(tfile);
end;
```

Why is it doing that?

Comment: If bFlag is a variable which is local to the procedure containing this code, it will have a quasi-random value when the procedure starts.  So, you should explicitky set its value to False before executing the `while not eof(tfile)` loop.  Also, consider using the `SameText` function to compare the user name with the line being read.

Comment: You are reading from- and writing to- the same tfile in this code. I suspect the eof gets set to true after the first write, which means that bflag was set to true on the 3rd line. Tell me I'm wrong.

Comment: @nolaspeaker That should not be a problem since OP is writing into a file outside the loop in which he is checking if the username already exists. At that point the code should have already looped through entire file.

Comment: You shouldn't expect readers to try and guess what your other code is doing, instead provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You could simplify your code for checking is username already exists. How? You could easily call `if Pos(Username+'#',sline) = 1 then //Username already exists`. How would this work? Well if `Pos` function returns position of a substring within a string. If the searched substring is at the start of the string 1 will be returned as result. If it is find in the middle of the line (perhaps someone used certain name as their password then the returned position will be greater than 1 so not matching username. And if the substring can't be found anywhere within the string the function will return 0.

Comment: ... And the reason why in previously mentioned code I'm adding `#` to username is to avoid `Pos` function to falesly detecting username if it is beginning par of another username like `Alex` is to `Alexis`

Comment: What does stepping through the code in the debugger tell you?

Comment: @SilverWarior I would use `StartsText()` or `StartsStr()` instead of `Pos()=1`. No need to search the whole string when you are only interested in the front of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide a sample file, but the reason for the code stopping to read the file after the third line can only be explained so, that you created the file originally with three names, in some text editor that uses CRLF as EOL (End Of Line) character(s).

In your code when you add new entries, you only write CR (#13) as you do in

```
Write(tfile, #13);
```

The allowed line break character(s) are defined by the `TTextLineBreakStyle` setting. It is declared as:

```
TTextLineBreakStyle = (tlbsLF, tlbsCRLF);
```

You are writing `#13` (CR), which alone is not a defined EOL character. To correct it you could change to write `#13#10`, or use the predefined constant `sLineBreak`.

See also `System.SetLineBreakStyle` in help.

> ```
> procedure SetLineBreakStyle(var T: Text; Style: TTextLineBreakStyle);
> ```
>
> Determines the end-of-line and end-of-file conventions for text file I/O.
>
> In Delphi, call SetLineBreakStyle to determine how text file routines find or mark the end of a line and the end of a file. Affected routines include Read, Write, ReadLn, Writeln, Eof, Eoln, SeekEof, and SeekEoln.